# Workflow copy to a new list

Tags: workflow

I have a list (Project tracker) that has a column (Resource) that allows for multiple entries. I'd like to figure out a workflow where:

1. An item is entered in the tracker and multiple names are added to the resource
2. the item is copied to a Resources table and listed multiple times (one time for each resource)

For example: 
In project tacker list: Project xyz Resources: Danielle, Karen, Debbie
copies to
Resource list
Project xyz Resource Danielle
Project xyz Resource Karen
Project xyz Resource Debbie

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we can achieve this with following workflow.

Set workflow variable: `test = current item: customers (return as Lookup Values, Comma Delimited)`

```
If workflow variable: test contain “user1”,
 Create new list item in TestCast list
If workflow variable: test contain  “user2”,
 Create new list item in TestCase list
… add other “if” clause for remains “users”.
```

But this only works when it is a finite number of “customers”. For a large number of “customers’, we are unable to create so many “If” clauses for it. In such scenario, I would like to suggest you to create new items from custom event receiver with Visual Studio instead.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e8bb0187-c5d4-4de6-a9f1-cc9958d82928/multiple-lookup-values-and-workflow-creating-multiple-items-in-new-list-from-lookup-values?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious